# Dynamic SQL query with cell reference in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, m

I have a query connected to a pivot table and I want it to show results based on a date from cell (so the user can change it without editing the query). I've read one way to do it is creating a connection to the cell

[image]

And drilling down that query so its data that can be referenced by another query

[image]

I've read I have to reference that connected table (just a date) through

```
    SQL1 = Text.Combine({SQL,Date}),
    SQL2 = Text.Combine({SQL1, "‘" }),
    
    Source = Sql.Database("servername", "db", [Query= SQL2])
```

So I think it should look like this:

```
let

SQL = 
"select     trim(codart) AS REF, 
            descart AS 'DESCRIPTION', 
            codalm AS WAREHOUSE, 
            descalm AS WAREHOUSEDESCRIP, 
            unidades AS UNITS, 
            entran AS 'IN', 
            salen AS 'OUT', 
            m.entran*1 + m.salen*-1 as MOVEMENT,
            (select sum(m1.entran*1 + m1.salen*-1)
                    from    MOVSTOCKS m1 
                    where   m1.codart = m.codart and m1.codalm = 
                m.codalm and m.fecdoc >= m1.fecdoc) as 'CUMULATIVE',
            PRCMEDIO as 'VALUE', 
            FECDOC as 'DATE', 
            REFERENCIA as 'REF', 
            tipdoc as 'DOCUMENT'
from        (select m.*,
            sum(m.entran*1 - m.salen*-1) over (partition by m.codart, m.codalm order by fecdoc) as cumulative,
            max(fecdoc) over (partition by m.codart, m.codalm) as max_fecdoc
                from MOVSTOCKS m
                where fecdoc <= ‘ ), m
                where fecdoc = max_fecdoc
and         (m.entran <> 0 or m.salen <> 0)
order       by fecdoc",
    
SQL1 = Text.Combine({SQL,Date}),
SQL2 = Text.Combine({SQL1, "‘" }),

Source = Sql.Database("servername", "db", [Query= SQL2])

in

   Source
```

The problem is... if that dynamic cell is formated as date, the power query shows this error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #date (2020, 9, 30) to type Text.
Details:
    Value= 30/09/2020
    Type=Type
```

And if I format date as text, then it shows this error (after changing privacy options):

```
DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near '‘'.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=SQL
    DataSourcePath=servername;db
    Message=Incorrect syntax near '‘'.
    Number=102
    Class=15
```

I want SQL to read this

```
where fecdoc <= ‘ ), m
```

as

```
where fecdoc <= 30/09/2020 ), m
```

Having in mind that date comes from an excel cell that can be changed by the user.

I'm new with SQL and M, I don't even know if what I'm trying makes any sense.

Any feedback will be helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with the `Text.Combine` steps  and the `‘` character?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I'm trying to connect that query to an spreadsheet cell (I created a connection in power query to a table with only that cell) with a Date, in this case, 30/09/2020

Comment: That didn't really answer my question. I don't understand how appending `Date` and `‘` to the SQL query is supposed to use the date in the query or what the line `where fecdoc <= ‘ ), m` is intended to do.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I added some extra info, please tell me if it is enough. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of whatever you're trying to do with `SQL1` and `SQL1`, in your query, replace

```
where fecdoc <= ‘ ), m
```

with

```
where fecdoc <= '" & Date & "' ), m
```

where `Date` is a reference to your date in string format.

Comment: Thank you, I think we are getting closer. Now it returns this error:

[Expression.Error] We cannot apply operator &  to types Text and DateTime

Details:

....                   from MOVSTOCKS m
                       where fecdoc <= '
                       Right=30/09/2020 0:00:00

Comment: It tells you exactly what the error is. You need to convert Date to the string format SQL expects.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I solved it with `where fecdoc <= '"&Text.From(Date)&"' ) m`